# Как удалить объект MSXML2.XMLHTTP?

Tags: vbscript

Цикл do работает, но o.responseText каждый раз один и тот же. Как каждый раз обновлять содержание o.responseText?

```
Dim o
    Dim x
    Dim b

Do
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET",

"http://.../message.txt",

False
o.send
b = o.responseText
MsgBox(o.responseText)
x = o.responseText
Set o = Nothing ' пытался очистить объект, но не выходит
WScript.Sleep 120000
Loop
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инициализируйте объект **прямо в цикле:**

```
Dim x
Dim b

Do
    Dim o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    o.open "GET",

    "http://.../message.txt",

    False
    o.send
    b = o.responseText
    MsgBox(o.responseText)
    x = o.responseText
    WScript.Sleep 120000
Loop

WScript.Quit
```

---

- *А в вашем случае, лучше инициализировать все переменные там.*

Comment: Я не оч понимаю, но кажется что он ответ от сервера кэширует или что ещё, протсо каждый раз в цикле выводит одно и то же. Хотя содержание на сервере меняется

Comment: @Georgiy Larionenko, попробуйте использовать мой код, если он не заработает, тогда посмотрим что ещё можно сделать.

Comment: Не заработал, но я уже нашел выход(добавил к ссылке рандомную переменную - каждый раз получается "новая ссылка").. Спасибо за помощь